# How to access dynamic field of object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a dictionary object that trough lookup i am injecting into an object

```
object = {
    _id: '2'
    power : 80,
    energy: 230
}
```

Then i want to access power or energy depending on input key property

```
input = {
   objectId: '2'
   key: 'energy'
}
```

In Javascript is easy to access dynamic field by `object[input.key]`

In mongoDB query i want something like this

```
db.getCollection('inputs').aggregate([
   { $lookup: { from: 'values', localField: 'objectId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'value' } },
   { $addFields: { value: { $arrayElemAt: ['$value', 0] } } },
   { $project: { value: '$value.{$key}', // where key is property of input
])
```

Comment: Maybe you can get the whole document and run a piece of custom js code against it

Comment: True, but i was expecting mongodb query syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution by constructing the query in Javascript

```
db.getCollection('inputs').aggregate([
   { $lookup: { from: 'values', localField: 'objectId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'value' } },
   { $addFields: { value: { $arrayElemAt: ['$value', 0] } } },
   { $project: { value: `$value.${key}`,
])
```

Notice ${key} this will be executed in JS and replaced with the value of the variable key

Answer (score 1):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.getCollection('inputs').aggregate([
   { $lookup: { from: 'values', localField: 'objectId', foreignField: '_id', as: 'value' } },
   { $project: {
     value: {
       $arrayToObject: {
         $filter: {
          input: { $objectToArray: { $arrayElemAt: ['$value', 0] }},
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$key"] }
        }
       }
     }
   }}
])
```